# Set standard legend key size with long label names ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am building a ggplot visualization in which some fill aesthetics have very long variable names, while other variable names are short. Adding long names changes the size of the legend key corresponding to the long text - lengthening it to match the text. I am wondering if there is a way to standardize the legend key height across all varibles, and change the spaces between the legend items.

I tried modifying `theme(legend.key.height())` and `theme(legend.key.width())` but that didn't solve the problem.

Here is example code:

```
#load neccesary package
library('ggplot2')

#create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(year = as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
                 class = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 
                 value = c(50, 50))

#Create plot
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = class)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'stack') + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c('This is an\nextremely\nlong label\nname', 'short label1', 'Another\nlong\nlabel\nname', 'short label3', 'short label4'))
```

Plots:

[image]

What I want is to have the same key size for all variables, with the white space between keys changing to accommodate the long text. So something that looks like this:

[image]

Trying `g + theme(legend.key.height = unit(3, 'mm'), legend.key.width = unit(3, 'mm'))`

Does not resolve the problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try adding `theme(legend.key.height=unit(2, "cm"))`

Comment: @Duck, thanks but that just makes all the legend keys large. I want to make them all small (I have a large number of variables to fit on the image).

Comment: You would have to play around the size of text in legend in that case!

Comment: @Duck: I tried editing the question to make it clearer what I want as a solution. Essentially i want to keep everything the same but simply make the key a common size, which would require expanding the whitespace in cases where there is a long title name.

Comment: For those who might be hoping for a less involved solution, this is a known issue tracked by https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3669. Currently (November 2021) it's open in the ggplot 3.4.0 milestone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: as of ggplot2 3.5.0, this method is probably broken. See other answer for a workaround.

You can do this by defining your own class of legends. This is of course more verbose than a simple option in the theme and it can be handy to know some gtable/grid, but it gets the job done.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

#create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(year = as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
                 class = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 
                 value = c(50, 50))

labs <-  c('This is an\nextremely\nlong label\nname', 'short label1', 
           'Another\nlong\nlabel\nname', 'short label3', 'short label4')

guide_squarekey <- function(...) {
  # Constructor just prepends a different class
  x <- guide_legend(...)
  class(x) <- c("squarekey", class(x))
  x
}

guide_gengrob.squarekey <- function(guide, theme) {
  # Make default legend
  legend <- NextMethod()

  # Find the key grobs
  is_key <- startsWith(legend$layout$name, "key-")
  is_key <- is_key & !endsWith(legend$layout$name, "-bg")

  # Extract the width of the key column
  key_col <- unique(legend$layout$l[is_key])
  keywidth <- convertUnit(legend$widths[2], "mm", valueOnly = TRUE)

  # Set the height of every key to the key width
  legend$grobs[is_key] <- lapply(legend$grobs[is_key], function(key) {
    key$height <- unit(keywidth - 0.5, "mm") # I think 0.5mm is default offset
    key
  })
  legend
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = class)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'stack') + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = labs,
                      guide = "squarekey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: If you want to edit the key background too:

```
guide_gengrob.squarekey <- function(guide, theme) {
  legend <- NextMethod()
  is_key <- startsWith(legend$layout$name, "key-")
  is_key_bg <- is_key & endsWith(legend$layout$name, "-bg")
  is_key <- is_key & !endsWith(legend$layout$name, "-bg")
  
  key_col <- unique(legend$layout$l[is_key])
  keywidth <- convertUnit(legend$widths[2], "mm", valueOnly = TRUE)
  
  legend$grobs[is_key] <- lapply(legend$grobs[is_key], function(key) {
    key$height <- unit(keywidth - 0.5, "mm")
    key
  })
  legend$grobs[is_key_bg] <- lapply(legend$grobs[is_key_bg], function(bg) {
    bg$height <- unit(keywidth, "mm")
    bg
  })
  legend
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i wanted. Extremely helpful. Will have to take a bit of time working through the code. Appreciate the time you took on this.

Comment: Just use `x <<- legend` somewhere in the guide_gengrob method code, run the plot and `x` is the legend object but now in your global environment; should you wish to inspect what all the subsetting and stuff does.

Comment: This is great, thank you @teunbrand! `guide_squarekey()` worked as a drop in replacement for a `fill = guide_legend()` I had.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to making a custom guide is to make a custom drawing function for the legend glyphs. The change relative to `draw_key_polygon()` is that the width and height are set to `"snpc"` units instead of `"npc"` units.

```r
#load neccesary package
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(rlang)

draw_square <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (is.null(data$size)) {
    data$size <- 0.5
  }
  lwd <- min(data$size, min(size) /4)
  grid::rectGrob(
    width  = unit(1, "snpc") - unit(lwd, "mm"),
    height = unit(1, "snpc") - unit(lwd, "mm"),
    gp = gpar(
      col = data$colour %||% NA,
      fill = alpha(data$fill %||% "grey20", data$alpha),
      lty = data$linetype %||% 1,
      lwd = lwd * .pt,
      linejoin = params$linejoin %||% "mitre",
      lineend = if (identical(params$linejoin, "round")) "round" else "square"
    )
  )
}

#create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(year = as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
                 class = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 
                 value = c(50, 50))

#Create plot
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = class)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'stack', key_glyph = draw_square) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c('This is an\nextremely\nlong label\nname', 'short label1', 'Another\nlong\nlabel\nname', 'short label3', 'short label4'))
g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>