# ggplot with fixed size for the panel (even if the legend contain long labels)

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating a graphic with ggplot, the size of the panel is adjusted with the other elements, for example the length of the labels in the legend.

We can see an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create data
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,  
  name2=c("A","B","C","D","E long, very long..... very very long........") , 
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)
  )


ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value,fill=name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value,fill=name2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

The problem is that if we create a series of graphics with different variables, the width of the bars is different.

My question is: is it possible to fix the size of the panel, and increase the width of the global ggplot graphic size to display legend?

(PS: one possibility is to create a legend in a separate graphic, but I would also like to explore the options for the overall size the ggplot graphics).

Answer (score 3):

You can control the length of the text using `str_wrap`

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value,fill=stringr::str_wrap(name2, 10))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Legend")+
  theme(legend.margin = margin(r=10,l=5,t=5,b=5))
```

[image]

Comment: awesome answer, thank you. One last question: is it possible to have squares in the legend? (instead of a rectangle because of the length of the string).

Comment: Check out this post here. They go another way to fiz the size of the text, but they also solve the size of the rectangles (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812949/set-standard-legend-key-size-with-long-label-names-ggplot?rq=1)