# Consistent legend key height in a vertical legend for fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, height, legend, fill

I would like to use a vertical legend in my plot. My legend labels are quite long and differ in the number of lines they take up. However, **I would like the legend to show consistent heights for each key**. So, in the plot below, **I would like all legend keys to be the same height** as the first (green) key. I can make all legend keys the same height if I *increase* the `legend.key.height`, but not if I *decrease* it.

I would rather a solution that works for multiple plots - I am outputting several hundred plots that each have different legends/text lengths.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "blue", "orange"),
                    labels = c("label with one line",
                               "label with\ntwo lines",
                               "label\nwith\nthree lines")) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.key.height = unit(0.1, "in"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9,
                                       margin = margin(t = 5, b = 5, unit = "pt")))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65812949/11374827

Comment: Ugh. You're probably right. I hadn't found that one.  I'm playing with a workaround that seems easier, but not quite there yet.