# Force keys size to be smaller in multiple lines legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

Is there any way to force legend key sizes to be independent from line height when we have legend text with multiple lines? I tried `legend.key.height`, `ggtext::element_textbox_simple`, and `guides` but none of them help to resize key legends independent from line height.

What I want is resize legend keys to be same size as the small grey ones while having my legend text exactly as it is.

[image]

Comment: See [Set standard legend key size with long label names ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812949/set-standard-legend-key-size-with-long-label-names-ggplot) for two options.

Comment: Thanks @stefan. I tried to apply that method but not sure how. It is a bit ambiguous where I need to use those functions (For instance inside `guides` or within `guide` arg in `scale_fill_manual`). Need to invest more time to undesrand that I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [second approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851215/12993861) by @teunbrand you could (probably) achieve your desired result by passing the custom draw key function by @teunbrand to the `key_glyph` argument of `geom_col`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on some fake data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1)

draw_square <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (is.null(data$size)) {
    data$size <- 0.5
  }
  lwd <- min(data$size, min(size) / 4)
  grid::rectGrob(
    width = unit(1, "snpc") - unit(lwd, "mm"),
    height = unit(1, "snpc") - unit(lwd, "mm"),
    gp = gpar(
      col = data$colour %||% NA,
      fill = alpha(data$fill %||% "grey20", data$alpha),
      lty = data$linetype %||% 1,
      lwd = lwd * .pt,
      linejoin = params$linejoin %||% "mitre",
      lineend = if (identical(params$linejoin, "round")) "round" else "square"
    )
  )
}

# create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = LETTERS[1:10],
  fill = sample(
    c(
      "Higher for men than for women",
      "No significant difference",
      "Higher for women than for men"
    ),
    10,
    replace = TRUE
  )
)

df$fill <- factor(df$fill, c(
  "Higher for men than for women",
  "No significant difference",
  "Higher for women than for men"
))

ggplot(df, aes(x = -x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col(
    key_glyph = draw_square, width = .8
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#5C3B73", "grey", "#974156"),
    labels = label_wrap_gen(28)
  ) +
  theme_void(
    base_size = 20,
    base_family = "Roboto"
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.key.spacing.y = unit(20, "pt"),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(5.5, 4), "pt"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#EDF6F9"),
    legend.justification = c(1, .95)
  ) +
  labs(fill = NULL)
```

[image]